# upgrade R version for Machine Learning Server for Windows

Tags: r, sql-server

Our sql server db admins followed the instructions outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/machine-learning-server/install/machine-learning-server-windows-install#download-machine-learning-server-installer) to bind the latest version of R. They used Machine Learning Server version (9.4.7) but when I run:

```
USE MyDatabase;

EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
@language=N'R'
,@script = N'
print(R.Version())
'
, @input_data_1 = N''
```

I only get version R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20). However, I want to install a package for version 3.5.3. How can I achieve this and why is the R version for SQL server so far behind? Thanks!

Comment: I still use 3.5.2, it is not that `"so far behind"`.

Comment: What package do you need to install, and what is the issue with using 3.5.2?

Comment: This package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rborist/index.html even  r-oldrel is for 3.5.3 ...

Comment: I appreciate that 3.5.2 is not that old but it can be an issue when new packages are on CRAN?

Comment: I also think that 8-9 months is a long time in the IT industry. You can grow a baby in this time (-: